# Let $A\in M_3(\mathbb{Q})$ so that $A^8=I_3$. Prove that $A^4=I_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_3(\mathbb{Q})$ so that $A^8=I_3$. Prove that $A^4=I_3$.
I tried to look at the solution provided by my book, but I can't understand it.
They say that $A$'s minimal polynomial divides the polynomial $P \in \mathbb{Q} [X] $, $P(x) =x^8-1=(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$(this is clear to me).
Suppose $A^4 \neq I_3$. Then among $A$' s characteristic polynomial's roots would be one of the roots of $x^4+1=0$(this is what I do not understand, why does this happen?). This of course is a contradiction since the degree of $A$' s minimal polynomial is $\le 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)(x^4+1)$ and is of degree $\leq 3$ as $A \in M_3$. This forces it to be a divisor of $(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1)$ (because $x^4+1$ is irreducible, and does not break into further factors, so it cannot be part of the factorization of $A$ by the degree constraint. This is similar to the fact that if $a|bc$ and $c$ is prime with $c \nmid a$ then $a | b$).

However, just note that $(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+1) = x^4 - 1$. Therefore, the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $x^4-1$, which means that $A$ satisfies $x^4 - 1$ : that is, $A^4 = I$.

---

As for the book itself, I will expand. The characteristic polynomial $p_A$ of $A$ is of degree $3$. The book is saying that if $A^4 \neq I$ then because $A$ satisfies $p_A(A) = 0$, the characteristic polynomial $p_A$ does not divide $x^4 - 1$. Therefore, some root $\alpha$ of the characteristic polynomial is not a root of $x^4-1$.

Next, because the minimal polynomial has the same roots as the characteristic polynomial, this root $\alpha$ is a root of $x^8-1$(since $A^8 =I$, we get that the minimal polynomial divides $x^8-1$, so $\alpha$ is a root of $x^8-1$) which is not a root of $x^4 - 1$. Therefore, it must be a root of whatever is left , which is $x^4+1$. But then, because $x^4+1$ is irreducible, $\alpha$ cannot be a root of a polynomial of smaller degree than $x^4+1$, which is a contradiction because we assumed it was a root of $p_A$.

So yes, basically my explanation is better.

---

The point is, over the real field $x^4+1$ will factorize into two more polynomials of degree $2$, so the argument above will fail if $x^4+1$ reduces because then the minimal polynomial could be one of the degree $2$ factors.

Comment: Thank you! This is way clearer than the solution in my book. I wonder, is $A$ necessarily a rational matrix? Can't it just be a real matrix?

Comment: I  am actually still editing, trying to clarify what the book was trying to say. It is slightly longer, so I think what I wrote is better than the book! Also, $A$ can be a real matrix, it seems.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your solution is indeed better, but I am still curious what they wanted to say.

Comment: Actually no, we are using the fact that the characteristic polynomial has rational coefficients here, because $x^4+1$ is not irreducible over the real numbers, it will factorize. The rationality of the entries is crucial, let me add that above.